# Why do I have an error: 'Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.' when using redux?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

So I have a movie app, and I have a page for a single movie. I have a section on that page where I display all of the videos from an API related to a certain movie.

So my Videos component looks like this:

```
const Videos = ({videos} :{videos:IVideos | null}) => {


  return (
    <div>{videos?.results.map((video, i) =>
            <div key={i}>{video.name}</div>
        )}</div>
  )
}
```

It's just a basic component which gets props from a higher component. But the main thing is redux slice, which looks like this:

Initial state:

```
const initialState: IMovieVideosState = {
    movieVideos: null,
    fetchStatus: null,
}
export interface IMovieVideosState {
  movieVideos: IVideos | null;
  fetchStatus: FetchStatus | null;
}
```

And finally slice:

```
const videosSlice = createSlice({
  name:'videos',
  initialState,
  reducers:{},
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder
      .addCase(fetchVideos.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.PENDING
      })
      .addCase(fetchVideos.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.SUCCESS
        state.movieVideos = action.payload
      })
      .addCase(fetchVideos.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.fetchStatus = FetchStatus.FAILURE
        //state.error = action.error.message
      })
  }
})
```

As you see, these are basic reducers, where if promise is successful I assign payload to an existing array.

And also thunk function:

```
export const fetchVideos = createAsyncThunk('videos/fetchVideos', async (id: number) => {
  const response = await axios.get<IVideos>(`${API_BASE}movie/${id}/videos?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
})
```

But in the browser I have the next error:

```
Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions.
```

And also another one:

```
A non-serializable value was detected in an action, in the path: `<root>`. Value: 
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
 
Take a look at the logic that dispatched this action:  
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

I have no idea why I could have these errors, because my reducer is the same as another one in my project, but this one doesn't work for some reason.

UseEffect for dispatching all reducers:

```
useEffect(() =>{
        dispatch(fetchDetail(Number(id)));
        dispatch(fetchCredits(Number(id)));
        dispatch(fetchPhotos(Number(id)));
        dispatch(fetchRecommended(Number(id)));
        dispatch(fetchSimilar(Number(id)));
        dispatch(fetchVideos(Number(id)));   //dispatching fetchVideos()
  }, [dispatch, id])
```

So in my case, all of the other functions work fine besides `fetchVideos()`.

Another example of a thunk for movie details:

```
export const fetchDetail = createAsyncThunk('detail/fetchDetail', async (id: number) => {
  const response = await axios.get<IMovie>(`${API_BASE}movie/${id}?api_key=${TMDB_API_KEY}`);
  console.log(response.data);
  return response.data;
})
```

My store file:

```
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

export const store = configureStore({
    reducer: {
      popular,
      top_rated,
      playing,
      upcoming,
      detail,
      credits,
      videos,
      photos,
      recommended,
      similar
    },
    middleware: [thunk]
  })
  
export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof store.getState>;
```

Comment: Seems like you havn't set up the thunk middleware. Can you show us where you create the store?

Comment: @NicholasTower sure, i edited my original question

Comment: i edited and added `middleware: [thunk]`, but the problem is still there

Comment: axios.get<IVideos> this returns a response not IVideos but im trying to find what the issue could be can you show the code where you invoke the thunk ?

Comment: @kodamace hi! i edited my original question and added the code

Comment: @Carl can you please show the thunk for one of the other actions ? like fetch detail I want to see something

Comment: @kodamace i added a code, you see, `fetchVideos` is similar to other thunks so i don't see why it's not working, i have another thunk which fetches photos and is called `fetchPhotos` and it works perfectly fine too

Comment: Ok i see so then the only thing left that I think would be the actual store file can you include that too cause I am thinking the reducer is maybe not named correctly or imported wrong ? lets see that then we can maybe have a solution but yeah this is a weird one hmmmm I must be missing something

Comment: @kodamace i also included my store code in the original question!

Comment: @Carl Yeah I know but i need to see where are you getting these reducer: {
      popular,
      top_rated,
      playing,
      upcoming,
      detail,
      credits,
      videos,
      photos,
      recommended,
      similar
    },

Comment: You must not add the thunk middleware yourself. Redux Toolkit has it already included. Other than that there doesn't seem to be a problem in the code you posted. I can't reproduce the error when I copy the code snippets.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using create Async Thunk method add think malware where you create store of videos then you can pass Async actions into it without nothing.

```
import { applyMiddleware, combineReducers, createStore } from "redux";
import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

// import your videos reducer here from file

export interface State {
  videos: IVideos;
}
const rootReducer = combineReducers<State>({
  videos: VideosReducer,
});
export const rootStore = createStore(
  rootReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);
```